# what is the alternative for $q or Q in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, q

I have been using `$q` for quite sometimes, it is working all fine. But lately for web workers the injection of `$q` is causing an issue. The Mangled, minified `q.js` is not able to detect functions which are used by Parallel.js. 
So is there an alternative way for `$q` or `q.js`

Or else how to exclude `q.js` from mangling.

Comment: If you add a little bit detail with your error log, may be it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: More info on the actual issue your having would help. don't forget `$q` is used in the core of angular, that's how all `$http` and the interceptors work. If you used an alternative angular won't. Besides that your willing to manually call `$scope.$apply` in every non-`$q` promise?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ES2015 native Promises (and some kind of [polyfill](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) for compatibility with older browsers of course, like `es6-shim`) as stated in this blog [post](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/12/18/exploring-angular-1.3-es6-style-promises.html).